# Strange SSIS Events in SysSSISLog

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, ssis-2012

We recently moved to SSIS2012 and SQL Server 2014.

I see strange events in the SysSSISLog in the database.

Here are the events that I've never overcome - 
"User:OnPostExecute"
"User:OnPreExecute"

Does anyone of you aware about these? I didn't get any clue in my research. I've also checked the procedure [dbo].[sp_ssis_addlogentry] to double confirm before posting.

PS: I know that there are events - 'OnPreExecute', 'OnPostExecute' but I'm unaware of the events which are PREFIXED by "USER:"

Answer (score 0):

**OnPreExecute**
Writes a log entry immediately before the executable runs.
**OnPostexecute**
Writes a log entry immediately after the executable has done its part.
Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140246.aspx